# Vertically centering UILabel programatically in scrollview that doesn't match the view swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uiscrollview, uilabel

I have a horizontal scrollview that fills 1/3rd of the view.

I want to put a UILabel in the centre of the scroll view, which I have successfully done with:

```
let reagentsLocationx = mainscrollview.frame.width/2-100
```

However, I am struggling to centre the label vertically within the scrollview. When I use similar code for reagentsLocationy it centres the label in the view and not within the scroll view.

How do I centre the label, in Swift, just within the scrollview?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you are using frame and not bounds. I don't believe frame will ever be larger than your screen space, but bounds it equal to the view's actual size. Try basing it on the bounds of the scroll views height.

`UIScrollView().contentSize.height` might be what you are looking for.

Comment: I had tried using bounds from another post I discovered but with no joy. I will try again and thank you for taking the time to respond.

Comment: I have tried using bounds and it still places the label in the vertical center of the screen and not the vertical center of the scrollview. The UIScrollView() suggestion keeps placing the label behind the clock so I guess it is equating to zero.

Comment: I use  UIScrollView() to represent any instance of a scroll view. According to a small amount of checking around this was the correct way of getting the middle of the scroll view if that is really what you are looking for. I would still divide by 2 and subtract or add the offset you desire from center.

Answer (score 0):

No need of setting sizes in code.

Everything done in the storyboard.

1. Drag your scrollview into your view controller.
2. Set top, bottom, leading and trailing constraints from the scrollview to the parent view or safe area.
3. Drag your text label into the scrollview.
4. Set your top, bottom, leading and trailing constraints to the scrollview.
5. IMPORTANT set a second leading and trailing constraint, now from the text label to the parent view  (UIView - not scrollview) or safe area.
   This makes sure that the text label knows his width and so the scrollview knows it too.